# Как вставить флэш баннер на страницу?

Tags: flash, html

Как вставить флэш баннер на страницу?

Comment: 1.Воспользоваться [поиском][1]!!!!!
2.Уточнить куда вставляете
3.если на html сайте или каком нить другом то [вот][2]


  [1]: http://www.google.com/
  [2]: http://forum.htmlbook.ru/index.php?showtopic=21255

Comment: Очередной вопрос из разряда почему небу синее а солнце светит, екстрасенсов сдесь нет, так что будьте так добры - вносите хоть какую-нибудь конкретику в то о чем вы пишите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А еще добавить `<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />` и в строку `embed wmode="opaque"`.
На для того, чтобы если на сайте есть элементы типа всплывающих окон с позицией `fixed` или `absolute` и т.п. находились над flash баннером, а не под ним!

В целом идеальный код таков:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="ширина" height="высота" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="путь к flash баннеру" />
<param name="quality" value="best" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="цвет фона | обычно #FFFFFF" />
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque" width="высота" height="ширина" src="тот же путь к баннеру" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" align="middle" name="имя баннера" bgcolor="цвет вона" quality="best"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: добавлю что это излишне ;)

Comment: AlexWindHope да вы спец по ходу... Что собственно излишне?

Answer (score 0):

Например, так

```
<object width="100" height="100" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="src" value="banner.swf" />
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100" height="100" src="banner.swf" quality="high">
</embed>
</object>
```

banner.swf - это имя того баннера, который надо вставить на HTML-страницу.